# EXT.NET 2.0 file upload field browse button not working

Tags: file, upload, field, ext.net

I'm trying to use file upload field. I used first example of the ext.net demo site. This link: http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/FileUploadField/Basic/

I run my code, but when I click the browse button, the window didn't open. I source about that.I researched this issue. And I found a source. This link: http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?15522-CLOSED-Programmatically-click-fileuploadfield-browse . In the source vladimir says: there is no way to open file dialog programaticaly (as I know, IE (not sure about IE9) allows it but other browsers don't support it)
The reason: security risk. I use IE9. So I download IETester program. I try my code but browse button did't open again. What should i do

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Fileuploadfield.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="Fileuploadfield" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
var showFile = function (fb, v) {
    if (v) {
        var el = Ext.get('fi-button-msg');
        el.update('<b>Selected:</b> ' + v);

        if (!el.isVisible()) {
            el.slideIn('t', {
                duration: .2,
                easing: 'easeIn',
                callback: function () {
                    el.highlight();
                }
            });
        } else {
            el.highlight();
        }
    }
};
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org 
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" ID="ResourceManager1" />
    <ext:FileUploadField ID="BasicField" runat="server" Width="400" Icon="Attach" />

        <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get File Path">
            <Listeners>
                <Click Handler="var v = #{BasicField}.getValue();  
                   Ext.Msg.alert('Selected&nbsp;File', v && v != '' ? v : 'None');" />
            </Listeners>
        </ext:Button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```